# ZK MVC problem.Seems UI can't connect to Controller using GenericForwardController

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, zk

this is actually my first ZK project seems pretty cool but not working and not throwing error either.

If i understand well the concept,server side can respond to interface action without me doing all the ajax plumbing work.I've wrote a small login app which does not perform any login per se but on click on submit should display a Messagebox.

here is my `index.zul` file

```
<window xmlns:n="native" id="win" apply="com.personal.project.admintest.event.LoginController">
<n:style type="text/css">
    button {
        color: #999999;
    }
    #center {
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%; left:50%;
    margin:-50px auto auto -100px;
    text-align:center;
    }
</n:style>
<n:div id="center">
    <groupbox id="gbLogin" mold="3d" width="300px">
        <caption label="login section" />
        <n:table>
            <n:tr>
                <n:td>
                    <label value="Username"/>
                </n:td>
                <n:td>
                    <textbox value="" id="txtUsername"/>
                </n:td>
            </n:tr>
            <n:tr>
                <n:td>
                    <label value="Password"/>
                </n:td>
                <n:td>
                    <textbox value="" id="txtPassword" type="password"/>
                </n:td>
            </n:tr>
            <n:tr  style="text-align: center">
                <n:td colspan="2">
                    <button id="btnSubmit" label="Login" width="70px" />
                </n:td>
            </n:tr>
        </n:table>
    </groupbox>

   </n:div>
</window>
```

and here is my `LoginController` file

```
import org.zkoss.zhtml.Messagebox;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.GenericForwardComposer;
import org.zkoss.zul.Textbox;
import org.zkoss.zul.Window;

public class LoginController extends GenericForwardComposer {
  Textbox txtUsername;
  Textbox txtPassword;
  Window win;


public void onClick$btnSubmit(){
   try {

    Messagebox.show(txtUsername.getText() + " and pass is " + txtPassword.getText());
    } catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately when i click on the button `Nothing Happens at all` and there is no error either :( . I'm sure i'm doing something wrong, i just can't find what it is.

I'would be grateful if somebody can point it out to me.

thanks for reading this.

Comment: I've tested your code, it works okay at my place, can you download a zkdemo war, and put your stuff into it and test again?

Comment: thanks! when i got home i tested it again and it started working.I can't  explain if it's caching or other issue.thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the code works.Can't say what went wrong the first times i've run it.
I would like to keep the question here because it might jut help someone get started.
Thanks for all who read it.